# How does std::find works with std::set

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, time-complexity

To find an element from a `std::set`, ofc, we should use `std::set::find`. However, the function `std::find`/`std::find` would work too.

```
std::set<int> st;
for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
    st.insert(i);
}

// method 1
if (st.find(999990) != st.end()) {
    std::cout << "111" << std::endl;
}

// method 2
auto itor = std::find(std::begin(st), std::end(st), 999990);
if (itor != std::end(st)) {
  std::cout << "aaa" << std::endl;
}

// method 3
auto itor2 = std::find(st.begin(), st.end(), 999990);
if (itor2 != st.end()) {
  std::cout << "bbb" << std::endl;
}
```

As you see, all of the the three methods work as exptected (https://godbolt.org/z/fEjzTae81).

But I don't know their difference, especially their complexity.

I just did a simple benchmark here: https://quick-bench.com/q/TjtOBZIWRw0oLg9_TywAlv45kmo

But I don't know why they have totally different complexity.

I know why `std::set::find` is fast. But I don't know why the two others are slow.

Does `std::find` totally **ignore** the order of `std::set` so that a `std::set` will be regarded as an sequence container like a `std::vector`? Or can I say that `std::find` doesn't know the fact that all of elements have been ordered so it does the search one by one (linear complexity)?

Why is `st.begin()` faster than `std::begin(st)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the time complexity difference is that `std::find` operates with iterators, and it, indeed, does treat `std::set` as a sequence container, while `std::set::find` uses container properties.

As for why `st.begin()` is faster than `std::begin(st)`, they are actually identical. The reason why second is faster is that both of your functions are doing the same thing, and as benchmarks are run consecutively, the execution of the second function is faster because probably cache misses are lower and similar things. I changed the order of these two functions and got exactly opposite result with `std::begin(st)` being faster. See this modified benchmark here: https://quick-bench.com/q/iM6e3iT1XbqnW_s-v_kyrs6kqrQ